# two sides pairing of nested set model? from parent perspective

Tags: mysql

so far i was able to retrieve 3 things the left children,right side children of a parent i've also added a depth limiter.
to best what model i've used look at this [Nested Set Model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)
if you select everything [this is what the table looks like my slight modified version from the Nested Set model from the last link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUV80.png)

this is my attempted query the problem here is that its pairing two things the right and some weird pair [the check is the correct the cross is the wrong one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xyjG.png)
this is what the tree looks like [to visualize the tree pairing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8ecB.png)

```
SET @VarToPairfind := 'ELECTRONICS';/*manually set*/
SET @VarFullRightSideKey :=0;/*dynamically set*/
SET @VarFullLeftSideKey :=0;/*dynamically set*/
SELECT @VarFullLeftSideKey:=node.lft+1 as fullLeft,@VarFullRightSideKey:=node.rgt-1 as fullRight FROM nested_category AS node where node.name=@VarToPairfind;
SET @VarFullRightSideKeyName :='';/*dynamically set*/
SET @VarFullLeftSideNameKey :='';/*dynamically set*/
SELECT @VarFullRightSideKeyName:=node.name From nested_category as node where node.rgt=@VarFullRightSideKey;
SELECT @VarFullLeftSideNameKey:=node.name From nested_category as node where node.lft=@VarFullLeftSideKey;
SET @rowno = 0;
SET @rownoleft = 0;
SET @rownoright = 0;
/*start of full side with depth limit*/
select * from (select @rowno:=@rowno+1 as rownos,LLL.name as LLL_name,LLL.myorder as LLL_myorder,LLL.depth as LLL_depth,LLL.lft as LLL_lft,LLL.rgt as LLL_rgt,ULR.name as ULR_name,ULR.myorder as ULR_myorder,ULR.depth as ULR_depth,ULR.lft as ULR_lft,ULR.rgt as ULR_rgt from (SELECT node.name,node.myorder,node.lft,node.rgt, (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent,
        nested_category AS sub_parent,
        (
                SELECT node.name,node.myorder, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth,node.lft,node.rgt
                FROM nested_category AS node,
                        nested_category AS parent
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                        AND node.name = @VarFullRightSideKeyName
                GROUP BY node.name
                ORDER BY node.lft
        )AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
        AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.name
HAVING depth > 1 and depth <= 2
ORDER BY node.lft) as ULR,
(SELECT node.name,node.myorder,node.lft,node.rgt,(COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent,
        nested_category AS sub_parent,
        (
                SELECT node.name,node.myorder, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth,node.lft,node.rgt
                FROM nested_category AS node,
                        nested_category AS parent
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                        AND node.name = @VarFullLeftSideNameKey

                GROUP BY node.name
                ORDER BY node.lft
        )AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
        AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.name
HAVING depth > 1 and depth <= 2
ORDER BY node.lft) as LLL where ULR.myorder!=LLL.myorder and ULR.depth=LLL.depth group by LLL.name,ULR.name) as sidetree;
```

VarToPairfind is the variable only given variable the rest are computed

this is the csv import file to workbench mysql
the table name is nested_category

```
category_id,name,lft,rgt,myorder
1,ELECTRONICS,1,30,right
2,TELEVISIONS,2,15,left
3,TUBE,3,8,left
4,LCD,9,14,right
6,"PORTABLE ELECTRONICS",16,29,right
7,"MP3 PLAYERS",17,22,left
8,FLASH,20,21,right
9,"CD PLAYERS",23,28,right
10,AIR,6,7,right
12,LIQUID,4,5,left
14,LED,12,13,right
17,BLUETOOTH,18,19,left
18,"BLUE RAY",26,27,right
19,DVD,24,25,left
20,FLORECENT,10,11,left
```

---

Updated version

```
SET @VarToPairfind := 'ELECTRONICS';/*manually set*/
SET @VarFullRightSideKey :=0;/*dynamically set*/
SET @VarFullLeftSideKey :=0;/*dynamically set*/
SELECT @VarFullLeftSideKey:=node.lft+1 as fullLeft,@VarFullRightSideKey:=node.rgt-1 as fullRight FROM nested_category AS node where node.name=@VarToPairfind;
SET @VarFullRightSideKeyName :='';/*dynamically set*/
SET @VarFullLeftSideNameKey :='';/*dynamically set*/
SELECT @VarFullRightSideKeyName:=node.name From nested_category as node where node.rgt=@VarFullRightSideKey;
SELECT @VarFullLeftSideNameKey:=node.name From nested_category as node where node.lft=@VarFullLeftSideKey;
SET @rowno = 0;
SET @rownoleft = 0;
SET @rownoright = 0;
/*start of full side with depth limit*/
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (select * from (select @rowno:=@rowno+1 as rownos,LLL.name as LLL_name,LLL.myorder as LLL_myorder,LLL.depth as LLL_depth,LLL.lft as LLL_lft,LLL.rgt as LLL_rgt,ULR.name as ULR_name,ULR.myorder as ULR_myorder,ULR.depth as ULR_depth,ULR.lft as ULR_lft,ULR.rgt as ULR_rgt from (SELECT node.name,node.myorder,node.lft,node.rgt, (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent,
        nested_category AS sub_parent,
        (
                SELECT node.name,node.myorder, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth,node.lft,node.rgt
                FROM nested_category AS node,
                        nested_category AS parent
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                        AND node.name = @VarFullRightSideKeyName
                GROUP BY node.name
                ORDER BY node.lft
        )AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
        AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.name
HAVING depth > 1 and depth <= 2
ORDER BY node.lft) as ULR,
(SELECT node.name,node.myorder,node.lft,node.rgt,(COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent,
        nested_category AS sub_parent,
        (
                SELECT node.name,node.myorder, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth,node.lft,node.rgt
                FROM nested_category AS node,
                        nested_category AS parent
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                        AND node.name = @VarFullLeftSideNameKey

                GROUP BY node.name
                ORDER BY node.lft
        )AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
        AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.name
HAVING depth > 1 and depth <= 2
ORDER BY node.lft) as LLL where ULR.myorder!=LLL.myorder and ULR.depth=LLL.depth group by LLL.name,ULR.name) as sidedtree);


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PairTable LIKE table2;
INSERT INTO PairTable select * from table2 where rownos%2=0 order by rownos desc limit 2; 
INSERT INTO PairTable select * from table2 where rownos%2=1 order by rownos asc limit 2; 
select * from PairTable;

/*DROPS TEMPORARY TABLE*/

DROP TABLE PairTable;
drop TABLE table2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imperfect solution but it does compare match the two

```
SET @VarToPairfind := 'ELECTRONICS';/*manually set*/
SET @VarFullRightSideKey :=0;/*dynamically set*/
SET @VarFullLeftSideKey :=0;/*dynamically set*/
SELECT @VarFullLeftSideKey:=node.lft+1 as fullLeft,@VarFullRightSideKey:=node.rgt-1 as fullRight FROM nested_category AS node where node.name=@VarToPairfind;
SET @VarFullRightSideKeyName :='';/*dynamically set*/
SET @VarFullLeftSideNameKey :='';/*dynamically set*/
SELECT @VarFullRightSideKeyName:=node.name From nested_category as node where node.rgt=@VarFullRightSideKey;
SELECT @VarFullLeftSideNameKey:=node.name From nested_category as node where node.lft=@VarFullLeftSideKey;
SET @rowno = 0;
SET @rownoleft = 0;
SET @rownoright = 0;
/*start of full side with depth limit*/
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (select * from (select @rowno:=@rowno+1 as rownos,LLL.name as LLL_name,LLL.myorder as LLL_myorder,LLL.depth as LLL_depth,LLL.lft as LLL_lft,LLL.rgt as LLL_rgt,ULR.name as ULR_name,ULR.myorder as ULR_myorder,ULR.depth as ULR_depth,ULR.lft as ULR_lft,ULR.rgt as ULR_rgt from (SELECT node.name,node.myorder,node.lft,node.rgt, (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent,
        nested_category AS sub_parent,
        (
                SELECT node.name,node.myorder, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth,node.lft,node.rgt
                FROM nested_category AS node,
                        nested_category AS parent
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                        AND node.name = @VarFullRightSideKeyName
                GROUP BY node.name
                ORDER BY node.lft
        )AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
        AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.name
HAVING depth > 1 and depth <= 2
ORDER BY node.lft) as ULR,
(SELECT node.name,node.myorder,node.lft,node.rgt,(COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent,
        nested_category AS sub_parent,
        (
                SELECT node.name,node.myorder, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth,node.lft,node.rgt
                FROM nested_category AS node,
                        nested_category AS parent
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                        AND node.name = @VarFullLeftSideNameKey

                GROUP BY node.name
                ORDER BY node.lft
        )AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
        AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.name
HAVING depth > 1 and depth <= 2
ORDER BY node.lft) as LLL where ULR.myorder!=LLL.myorder and ULR.depth=LLL.depth group by LLL.name,ULR.name) as sidedtree);


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PairTable LIKE table2;
INSERT INTO PairTable select * from table2 where rownos%2=0 order by rownos desc limit 2; 
INSERT INTO PairTable select * from table2 where rownos%2=1 order by rownos asc limit 2; 
select * from PairTable;

/*DROPS TEMPORARY TABLE*/

DROP TABLE PairTable;
drop TABLE table2;
```